# cygwin- cd /cygdrive/c/path not working

Tags: cygwin

i have installed 1.7.9 version of cygwin. Iam trying to do cd "/cygdrive/c/path" from .sh file. When iam trying to execute that shell script its throwing an error as below
cd /cygdrive/c/path no such file or directort exist.

Please help

If i execute any command from cygwin terminal, all commands are working fine, but if i put those scripts in .sh and try to execute the .sh scripts from cygwin terminal, its not working. I have added the CYGWIN_HOME and environment variable path also.

Please help any kind of setup needs to be done for shell script to execute on cygwin terminal

In Shell Script have entered below things for testing purpose

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/DCS/"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
echo "$5"
echo "$6"
echo "$7"
echo "$8"
mv "./conf/env.conf_$3" "./conf/env.conf"
```

I executed ls -la /cygdrive/c command. Check the below permission for DCS folder

```
drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users          0 Oct 29 17:26 DCS
```

Iam Invoking the script and gettig the below error

```
$ ./run.sh
: No such file or directory line 1: cd: /cygdrive/c/DCS/
app
0.4.2
DEV
test
test
NO
both
0.4.1
mv: cannot stat `./conf/env.conf_DEV\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please give a "minimum working example" of a shell script that gives you the error, along with a description of how the script is invoked.

Comment: I have a shell script which contains cd "/cygdrive/c/path" and mv command.. Iam trying to invoke the script directly on cygwin terminal as ./test.sh

As soon as i execute , it is throwing an error as below
------------------------------------------------------------
: No such file or directory line 9: cd: /cygdrive/c/DCS
mv: cannot stat `./conf/env.conf_DEV\r': No such file or directory

Comment: Please *update your question* to show the actual complete script. Don't just write "path", show us the actual path you're using. (As xnor's answer suggests, I suspect a problem with spaces in the path you're using.)

Comment: How are the arguments `$1` to `$8` being provided if you are invoking your script without any arguments?

Comment: Which shell are you using, specifically?

Comment: I am using bash shell. I am passing the argument from another shell script. run.sh script called inside another shell script with parameters

Comment: Above issue is resolved. Please check the below link


http://superuser.com/questions/189259/cygwin-cd-in-bash-script?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Do a `ls -la /cygdrive/c` to see if the path is really there.

In your shell script make sure you're correctly escaping or quoting the paths, like so `mv "/cygdrive/c/path to file" /cygdrive/c/path\ to\ target`.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the script from a new vi session..
try it with a simple cd command .
if you wrote the script in notepad or another editor, there may be other escape characters..
worked for me just fine

Comment: i edited a file in notepat. for example 
cd /application/Files/In
If the file is transferred between windows and cygwin, then there are probably escape characters or something else that cause the specific error.
Rewrite the code in your file from a scratch file ( i use vi editor and it is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

What does `pwd` output? If it is `/home/UserName` then that is the issue. The default shell for mintty is specified in `/etc/passwd`. If it does not exist, do the following:

Run mintty.exe as administrator and enter: `mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

This will set `/cygdrive/c/Users/Name` as the home directory. I hope this will solve the problem!

For more information: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html#:~:text=The%20mkpasswd%20program%20can%20be,disconnected%20from%20its%20domain%20controller.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a proper `shebang` on the first line.
Modify the script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/cygdrive/c/DCS/"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
echo "$5"
echo "$6"
echo "$7"
echo "$8"
mv "./conf/env.conf_$3" "./conf/env.conf"
```

you invocation

```
$ ./run.sh
```

assume that the script contains information about which program should execute it
and the error says that it does not found it

```
: No such file or directory line 1: cd: /cygdrive/c/DCS/
```